# How to Remove a Administration Console User of TFS 2010

Tags: windows, tfs, administration

My Team Foundation Server(TFS)2010 has an old Administrator account listed in the "Administration Console Users".

I add a new account to "Administration Console Users". And then i try to remove the old one.
So i select the old one, and click "remove" button. It begins to do some work.

However, after finishing that work, the old account still stay in the "Administration Console Users".

How can i remove the old one, leaving the new account stay here only?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps to add user as a admin:-

1. Add user in admin console
2. Add user in "Team Foundation Service Accounts"

Add button in the console wizard will add user only in admin console.

To add user in "Team Foundation Service Accounts" group, use following command:-
tfssecurity /g+ "Team Foundation Service Accounts" n:domain_name\user_name /server:SERVER_URL

There is only one step to remove user from admin group:-

Just click on the remove button in the console wizard. It will remove user from console as well as from "Team Foundation Service Accounts" group.

Comment: TFSSecurity command is working fine to add/remove active AD users.. when I try to remove inactive (AD) user from Team Foundation Service Accounts group it is giving out Error: The identity cannot be resolved.